# Create PDF from view layout using PDFDocument android

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf-generation, pdfdocument

I am trying to create PDF file of A4 paper size from an android app from xml view using native PDFDocument library. I want to generate a pdf with single page that displays some information. I am facing a problem wrapping the view contents in the page correctly. I have attached the outcome with some mock data.

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRVm3.jpg)

How can i make the view content to auto fit in the specified page size (A4 equivalent 595, 842) without overlapping one another.
My implementation

```
val pdfDocument = PdfDocument()
val pageInfo =
     PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1)
         .create()
val page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo)
 
val pageCanvas = page.canvas
val pageWidth = pageCanvas.width
val pageHeight = pageCanvas.height
 
val measuredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pageWidth, 
View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
val measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pageHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)

view.measure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight)
view.layout(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight)
view.draw(pageCanvas)
pdfDocument.finishPage(page)
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm running into a similar issue trying to make my view scale to fit an A4 paper size.